# all pairs of consecutive lines sharing a field, using awk

Tags: bash, awk, gawk

I would like to process a multi-line, multi-field input file so that I get a file with all pairs of consecutive lines ONLY IF they have the same value as field #1.

This is, for each line, the output would contain the line itself + the next line, and would omit combinations of lines with different values at field #1.

It's better explained with an example.

Given this input:

```
1 this
1 that
1 nye
2 more
2 sit
```

I want to produce something like:

```
1 this 1 that
1 that 1 nye
2 more 2 sit
```

So far I've got this:

```
awk 'NR % 2 == 1 { i=$0 ; next } { print i,$0 } END { if ( NR % 2 == 1 ) { print i } }' input.txt
```

My output:

```
1 this 1 that
1 nye 2 more
2 sit
```

As you can see, my code is blind to field #1 value, and also (and more importantly) it omits "intermediate" results like `1 that 1 nye` (once it's done with a line, it jumps to the next pair of lines).

Any ideas? My preferred language is awk/gawk, but if it can be done using unix bash it's ok as well.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this awk:

```
awk 'NR>1 && ($1 in a){print a[$1], $0} {a[$1]=$0}' file
1 this 1 that
1 that 1 nye
2 more 2 sit
```

Comment: Nice! I see I was pretty far away from the answer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you explain the meaning of the last `{}` block please?

Comment: Why `print a[$1] OFS $0` vs `print a[$1], $0`?

Comment: Yes indeed it should be `print a[$1], $0` for shorter code. @XGrau: Last `{a[$1]=$0}` is populating an array `a` with key as `$1` and value as full line.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with simple commands. Assuming your input file is "test.txt" with content:

```
1 this
1 that
1 nye
2 more
2 sit
```

following commands gives the requested output:

```
sort -n test.txt > tmp1
(echo; cat tmp1) | paste tmp1 - | egrep '^([0-9])+ *[^ ]* *\1'
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun

```
paste -d" " filename <(sed 1d filename) | awk '$1==$3'
```